# Difference between "preisgünstig", "billig" and "preiswert"?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, difference

I have studied German for a few weeks. When I consult the dictionaries, I do not get any differentiation.

Are there any differences between *preisgünstig*, *billig* and *preiswert*?

Are there any nuances?

Comment: "billig" can have a negative touch meaning that something is not good enough, looks bad etc.

Comment: You should consult a better dictionary. "Billig" has some distinct additional meanings that aren't covered by "preisgünstig" and "preiswert".

Comment: @Em1: Thanks for the help with updating the posting. I will consult an English-German dictionary from now on. Any recommendations?

Comment: @Eva it's never a bad idea to ask leo: https://www.leo.org/ Preiswert and Presigünstig already give a statement about the price so either it is a reasonable price or even a good price ;)

Comment: I highly recommend staying away from Leo, unless you have a very thorough knowledge of both languages. For beginners, I recommend any bilingual dictionary that categorize translations. E.g. at pons.eu "billig" is put into the catgorizes "preisgünstig" (inexpensive car), "minderwertig" (shabby old jeans), "oberflächlich" (cheap jokes). Pons can also be used as a monolingual dictionary. This is quite important to learners to understand a meaning better, because translations cannot really convey the actual sense good enough.

Comment: @CarstenS Jemand(TM) müsste die verlinkte Frage mal noch ins Englische übersetzen - die Antworten sind es kurioserweise schon.

Comment: @Matthias, deshalb war mir auch gar nicht aufgefallen, dass die Frage auf deutsch ist, obwohl ich danach geschaut hatte.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### billig

This is the oldest als still most frequent used word out of this group. The original, but nowadays mostly forgotten meaning was: »appropriate, adequate, suitable, ...«. Today there still is a phrase where »billig« is used in this meaning:

> etwas ist recht und billig

In this phrase »recht« means »according to the laws«, and »billig« means »suitable with common usage«. Also in the verb »billigen« you have this old meaning. »Etwas billigen« means »to approve something«.

But in modern German »billig« means »mit angemessenem Preis« (»with adequate price«) which is just another way to say »cheap«.

But »billig« as well as »cheap« often does not only mean »with a low price«, but very often also »with low quality«, i.e. »worthless«.

So marketing experts didn't like the adjective »billig«, because it is connotated with »worthless«. And it's hard to sell something when you say that it is worthless. So they invented other words:

---

### preiswert

This word came up at the end of 19th century, and was invented my marketing people to have a word that still means »with adequate price«, but by adding »Wert« (»value« in english), it no longer can mean »worthless«.

So, »etwas ist preiswert« means: something has a high value but a low price.

---

### günstig

You didn't explicitly ask for this word, but it also belongs to this group of words. »Günstig« is also an old German word. It is derivated from the noun »Gunst« (the favor). It has three meanings:

1. cheap

   > Die Äpfel sind heute sehr günstig.
   >   Apple are very cheap today.
2. advantageous

   > Das Wetter ist sehr günstig für Bergsteiger.
   >   The weather is very advantageous for mountaineers.
3. favorable

   > Wir müssen auf einen günstigeren Moment warten.
   >   We have to wait for a more favorable moment.

---

### preisgünstig

You can find this word during World War II, but it's wide usage started in the 1950ies. Again it was marketing people who invented this word. It is an improvement of »günstig«. »Preis« in front of »günstig« forces the meaning of »günstig« to #1 (cheap). But since »günstig« also has the meanings »advantageous« and »favorable«, the negativ worthless-connotation, that always comes together with »billig« is banned.

Comment: [Marketing experts *do* often use *billig* and seem to not care about the second meaning.](https://www.google.com/search?site=&tbm=isch&source=hp&biw=1260&bih=852&q=billiger&oq=billiger&gs_l=img.3..0l10.423.1130.0.1212.8.7.0.0.0.0.147.656.4j3.7.0....0...1ac.1.64.img..1.7.651...0i10k1.a2P4chE63WI)

Comment: I cannot agree with the definition of *preiswert*. You said *something has a high value but a low price* . Something must not have a high value, in order to be able to be *preiswert*. A tootbrush can also be *preiswert*. I think here, price performance ratio plays a more important role than the value of the product.

Comment: @AdInfinitum Maybe not high value, but definitely *value*. Duden: "im Verhältnis zu seinem Wert nicht [zu] teuer". So "preiswert" does imply that something is of value. How high that value is, will depend. A Rolls Royce for 100,000 Euros is probably "preiswert", as is a toothbrush for 2 Euros.

Comment: @Hubert You might want to add that "preiswert" and "preisgünstig" are synonymous or make it clear how their meanings differ.

Answer (score 1):

The dictionary says;

**Preisgünstig**

> so, dass man für relativ wenig Geld relativ gut kaufen kann. 
>   
>  Synonyme:  preiswert

**Billig**

> so, dass für eine Ware oder Dienstleistung ein vergleichsweise
>   niedriger Preis verlangt wird.

**Preiswert**

> so, dass man für relativ wenig Geld relativ gut kaufen kann.
>   Synonyme: preisgünstig

I try to explain these words and their differences.

From these definitions, it could be understood that *preisgünstig* and *preiswert* are **synonym** and they mean; with little money, you can shop good or buy a product with a good price.

From the defitinition, it can be roughly said that most of the products cost similar prices, when one of them (I name it, product X) costs less. In this case, you can say, Product X ist billig.

Comment: preisgünstig and preiswert= "value for money". Vielen dank, Ad. I awarded you the points.

Comment: For example, you can buy a very expensive product and you can say it was worth to buy this product with this money but it must not mean that it is preisgünstig / preiswert. I think you should have this feeling for a product, this product may cost more than its current price.

Comment: @Eva: »preiswert« can be interpreted as »value for money« (in fact it means »low price for high value«, but »preisgünstig« has a different meaning. Read my answer for more details.

Comment: @Eva I think, the Hubert's answer, which contains more details, should be accepted answer.

Comment: @Ad Infinitum 1: Thanks for being ehrlich. I awarded you the points because you were first. I have awarded Hubert the points. Vielen dank.

Comment: @Eva When I ask a question, I always wait for a while because someone write very quicky but roughly, while the other writes very detailed, which may last a long time. I think you can always change the accepted answer, if a better answer comes. Being first should help if and only if there are similar answer but not better at all.

Comment: @Ad*: I fully agree with you but sometimes I am timed out from being able to add comments, accept responses and edit/add comments so I accept and change later when I have time. If the site times me out then at least someone got the points.